# What does <= operator do with dict items

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling with understanding how the `<=` operator works.

I have one list with one dictionary element (just one element) called `result`:

```
dict_items([('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])
```

I also have list of dictionary elements (more than one) called `data`:

```
dict_items([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])
dict_items([('name', 'Bob'), ('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])
dict_items([('name', 'Charlie'), ('AGATC', '3'), ('AATG', '2'), ('TATC', '5')])
```

Code that is problematic is here:

```
# Check if any person in csv file matches output from dna_count
for row in data:
    if result.items() <= row.items():
        print(row["name"])
```

I understand that it checks if any row of data matches element of result, and if it does then it prints name from that row, but why operator `==` isn't working there and I need to use `<=`, and how does `<=` behave because in `result` there is no name key, does it skip name key?

Comment: Define "operator == isn't working"…?!

Comment: @deceze when I used: if result.items() == row.items(): my program wasn't working, just checked it again it was skipping my if statement and wasn't printing name of row while <= was doing it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. If all values are hashable, so that `(key, value)` pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like. [..] For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class `collections.abc.Set` are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

So, you *can* use set comparison operators here, and `result.items() <= row.items()` tests if `result.items()` is a [*subset*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of `row.items()`. Subset means that it contains *some* items but not any other items.

Which is obviously what makes this comparison true:

> ```
> dict_items([('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])
>
> dict_items([('name', 'Bob'), ('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])
> ```

The first "set" here is a subset of the second, but it's not *equal* (because it's missing one item).